# Am I right with this limit?

Tags: limits, solution-verification, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

Say I have $f(x)$ defined as

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 40 & x \geq 10000 \\ -3x & x < 10000\end{cases}$$

Here I understood rather easily that $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x) = 40$.

But now I have this:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} -x & x\in\mathbb{Q} \\\\ 2 & x\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$$

How to get, if existent, the limit for $x\to+\infty$?

SO I thought: when I go to infinity, I can go though "rational steps" or "non rational steps". Either ways, I can reach infinity so a priori I cannot exclude any of the two options.

So the limit doesn't exist, and I thought it to be for some similar reason of when we study what happens at the infinity for $(-1)^n$. If it's "an even infinity" then limit is $1$, whereas it's $0$ for an odd infinity.

Am I right or wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: You are right. Phrased more formally, you have correctly observed that for the limit to exist, for every sequence "going to infinity", the value of its limit must be the same. If we take a sequence in the rationals, the sequence diverges to $-\infty$. If we take a sequence in the irrationals, the sequence is convergent to $2$. Thus, the limit does not exist, as different sequences give different values for the limit.

Comment: Indeed, for *any* function defined as $-x$ on the rationals, the limit as $x\to\infty$ will fail to exist regardless of its definition on irrationals. The nicest we could hope for is for the function to tend to $-\infty$ (that limit still doesn't exist, but in a way we can describe), and even that doesn't happen for this specific example.